# Replace a string with a value from an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, for-loop, str-replace

I want to plot a graph using my x-coordinates. The x-coordinates are given in an array. How do I replace a string with my x-coordinates array?

This is what I have tried to do but it doesn't seem to work, it only gives one dot or plot only one point.
This is the code where I want to replace the x-coordinates.

```
$x2 = $_SESSION['roots'];
```

`$x2` is an array that I took from my other php page.

```
 for ($i=0; $i < $GLOBALS['width'] * 50 / $GLOBALS['scale']; $i++)
   {

      $X = 0;
      $Y = 0;
      pixelsToCart($X, $Y);

for($j=0; $j<count($x2); $i++){

      $X = $x2[$j]/50;

     @eval("\$Y = " . str_replace('x', '$X', $equation  ) . ";");

     plot($build, $X, $Y);
}
  }
```

How do I replace the x-coordinates with the array provided?

Comment: without knowing what `$equation` is and where it came from, try replacing your eval line with `$Y = str_replace('x', $X, $equation)`

Comment: @Rob sorry, actually $equation is my users input variable where there insert any equation to plot the graph. and i have tried as you suggested but it doesn't work. thanks anyway for the suggestion.